# Complex Junit Testing case

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I am trying to create a JUnit test for this class.

What is the best way to go about testing the different if-else statements.

The I tried some generic unit test cases.

```
public class ObjectClaimHistory {

    private List<ObjectCollaborationClaimHistory> objectClaimHistory = new ArrayList<>();

    public void checkClaim(ClaimRequest claimRequest, Set<Integer> outOfDateCommits, int collaborationId, Integer parentCollaborationId, ClaimConflicts conflicts) {
        Set<Integer> conflictingCollaborationClaims = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Integer> conflictingCollaborationBlocks = new HashSet<>();
        for (ObjectCollaborationClaimHistory collaborationClaimHistory: objectClaimHistory) {
            if (!collaborationClaimHistory.checkClaim(claimRequest, outOfDateCommits)) {
                conflictingCollaborationClaims.add(collaborationClaimHistory.getCollaborationId());
            }
            if (!collaborationClaimHistory.checkBlock(claimRequest, outOfDateCommits)) {
                conflictingCollaborationBlocks.add(collaborationClaimHistory.getCollaborationId());
            }
        }
        // After checking all histories create one commit conflict. Choose the closest collaboration.
        if (conflictingCollaborationClaims.contains(collaborationId)) {
            conflicts.addCommitConflict(claimRequest.getObjectId(), claimRequest.getClaim(), collaborationId);
        }
        else if (conflictingCollaborationBlocks.contains(collaborationId)) {
            conflicts.addCommitConflict(claimRequest.getObjectId(), claimRequest.getBlock(), collaborationId);
        }
```

Comment: I don't quite see what is so complex about that test. You just give it mock versions of classes (for example, a CollabClaimHistory that always returns `false`) and verify whatever comes out as a result.

Comment: We usually use some IDE and write some code in a test class. What do you mean by "best way"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then ...

You want to control the behaviour of the `collaborationClaimHistory` instances such that in some test scenarios it returns true and in others it returns false for these invocations:

- `collaborationClaimHistory.checkClaim(claimRequest, outOfDateCommits)`
- `collaborationClaimHistory.checkBlock(claimRequest, outOfDateCommits)`

You want to assert that the commitConflicts added to the given `ClaimConflicts` are valid.

Looking at the code I see this: `for (ObjectCollaborationClaimHistory collaborationClaimHistory : objectClaimHistory)` which makes me suspect that `objectClaimHistory` is somehow injected into or discovered by `ObjectClaimHistory`. For your test you must be able to control how that is populated such that it returns instances of `CollaborationClaimHistory` which you can tweak to meet your test scenarios.

Here's an example which assumes that `objectClaimHistory` is injected when creating `ObjectClaimHistory`:

```
@Test
public void someTest() {
    CollaborationClaimHistory collaborationClaimHistory = Mockito.mock(CollaborationClaimHistory.class);

    ObjectClaimHistory sut = new ObjectClaimHistory(Lists.newArrayList(collaborationClaimHistory));

    ClaimRequest claimRequest = ...;
    Set<Integer> outOfDateCommits = ...;
    int collaborationId = ...;
    Integer parentCollaborationId = ...;
    ClaimConflicts conflicts = ...;

    // set up expectations on the collaborationClaimHistory instance which will be interrogated within the sut
    Mockito.when(collaborationClaimHistory.checkClaim(claimRequest, outOfDateCommits)).thenReturn(true);

    sut.checkClaim(claimRequest, outOfDateCommits, collaborationId, parentCollaborationId, conflicts);

    // assert that the response (which is implicit in th post invocation state of conflicts) is valid
    assertTrue(conflicts.hasCommitConflict(claimRequest.getObjectId(), claimRequest.getClaim(), collaborationId));

    // ... and repeat for other scenarios, multiple CollaborationClaimHistory instances etc
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

To check each if and else if statement you would need to create multiple unit test and pass in an argument for every case that each if and else if statement is expecting i.e. you would create 4 test cases for your method and give it 4 arguments. Another way to test which is not recommend and is a bad way of doing but quite quick and easy is to add assertTrue statements in each if and else if statement this will check if the input is given and is correct at runtime. Let me know if you need any more help or example code

Answer (score 0):

1. Leverage the `setup` (@Before) method to create a robust test fixture, mocking collaborators that have dependencies on external resources, e.g., DB, Queue.  Create member variables in the test class to hold the test collaborators and set their state in the `setup` method.  This gives the test methods the ability to change them as needed for a given test.
2. In each test, change the test fixture if necessary to achieve the satisfy the conditions of the test.  Since a test should only fail for one reason, you'd ideally only change one aspect of the test fixture.  A well thought out test fixture goes a long way toward preventing unintended side-effects caused by an incomplete test set up.  All that remains is to invoke the unit under test and assert the expected outcome.
3. Use a code coverage tool to track your progress.  You'd be surprised how many times you write too many tests for a production method.

If you follow this approach, it will take longer to set up the fixture, but there will be less repeated code in the tests themselves.  The reward is that once the fixture is set up, the tests are usually very short, are completed quickly, and make an excellent foundation for adding more tests in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    class ObjectClaimHistoryTest {
    private int colId = 1001;
    private Set<Integer> out = Set.<Integer>of(1, 2, 3);
    private ObjectClaimHistory objectClaimHistory = new ObjectClaimHistory();

    @Test
    void test(@Mock ClaimRequest cr, @Mock ClaimConflicts cc,
            @Mock ObjectCollaborationClaimHistory objectCollaborationClaimHistory) {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(objectClaimHistory, "objectClaimHistory",
                List.of(objectCollaborationClaimHistory));
        when(objectCollaborationClaimHistory.getCollaborationId()).thenReturn(1001);
        objectClaimHistory.checkClaim(cr, out, colId, cc);
        when(objectCollaborationClaimHistory.checkClaim(eq(cr), eq(out))).thenReturn(true);
        when(objectCollaborationClaimHistory.checkBlock(eq(cr), eq(out))).thenReturn(true);
        objectClaimHistory.checkClaim(cr, out, colId, cc);
        when(objectCollaborationClaimHistory.checkBlock(eq(cr), eq(out))).thenReturn(false);
        objectClaimHistory.checkClaim(cr, out, colId, cc);
    }

}
```